# Unable to read double from application resource within the viewmodel class

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, resourcedictionary, idioms

I have defined a resource in App.xaml which am trying to read from a view model class.

Different versions which were tried

```
<OnPlatform x:Key="HandpickedPhone"
                    x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
                    Android="250"
                    iOS="240" />
        <OnPlatform x:Key="HandpickedTablet"
                    x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
                    Android="375"
                    iOS="360" />
        <OnIdiom x:Key="HandpickedHeight"
                 x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
                 Phone="{StaticResource HandpickedPhone}"
                 Tablet="{StaticResource HandpickedTablet}" />

<OnPlatform x:Key="HorizontalListHeight"
                    x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
            <OnPlatform.Android>
                <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
                         Phone="250"
                         Tablet="375" />
            </OnPlatform.Android>
            <OnPlatform.iOS>
                <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
                         Phone="240"
                         Tablet="260" />
            </OnPlatform.iOS>
        </OnPlatform>
```

I am trying to read it and set the height request dynamically like,

```
double height = (double)App.Current.Resources["HorizontalListHeight"];
                        horizontalStack.HeightRequest = height;
```

But casting to double throws IllegalCastException, and at the same time, I am able to cast into the correct value from the watcher in VS.

Comment: try Double.Parse()

Comment: Directly use in your xaml code <HorizontalStack HeightRequest="{StaticResource HorizontalListHeight}"/>

Comment: @HamidShaikh cant use in xaml dynamically I have to set it, depending on the scenario

Comment: In Xaml also you can do it dynamically using triggers.... <StackLayout.Triggers> <DataTrigger TargetType="StackLayout" Binding="{Binding PropertyOnWhichChangeIsRequired}" Value="True"><Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="{StaticResource HorizontalListHeight}" />......

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Width or Height or Thickness in x:TypeArguments
Like this:-

```
       <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
            <OnPlatform.Platforms>
                <On Platform="iOS" Value="0, 20, 0, 0" />
                <On Platform="Android" Value="0, 0, 0, 0" />
                <On Platform="UWP" Value="0, 0, 0, 0" />
            </OnPlatform.Platforms>
        </OnPlatform>
```

Comment: so "x:Double" is not a valid TypeArgument. HeightRequest expects a double hence i gave Double as the argument. Will check with height. And my requirement is to have different values for different Idiom as well.

Comment: unable to find TypeArgument Height

Answer (score 0):

First , check https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/354754/#Comment_354754.

Here `height` is not `double` , it is `OnPlatform<double>` , so modify your code as

```
 var height = (OnPlatform<double>)App.Current.Resources["HorizontalListHeight"];
 horizontalStack.HeightRequest = height;
```

However , it's not the recommended way , we often use `Style` in ResourceDictionaty.

```
       <Style x:Name="HorizontalListHeight" TargetType="StackLayout">
            <Setter Property="HeightRequest">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <OnPlatform  x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                        <OnPlatform.Android>
                            <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double"  Phone="250" Tablet="375" />
                        </OnPlatform.Android>
                        <OnPlatform.iOS>
                            <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double" Phone="240" Tablet="260" />
                        </OnPlatform.iOS>
                    </OnPlatform>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

horizontalStack.Style = Application.Current.Resources["HorizontalListHeight"] as Style;
```